# How to create new data frames in a for loop

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I want to condense the following code into a for loop:

```
day1 = data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, "outcome" = outcome, "age" = age, "day" = days[,1], "val" = val[,1]))
day2 = data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, "outcome" = outcome, "age" = age, "day" = days[,2], "val" = val[,2]))
day3 = data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, "outcome" = outcome, "age" = age, "day" = days[,3], "val" = val[,3]))
day4 = data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, "outcome" = outcome, "age" = age, "day" = days[,4], "val" = val[,4]))
day5 = data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, "outcome" = outcome, "age" = age, "day" = days[,5], "val" = val[,5]))
day6 = data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, "outcome" = outcome, "age" = age, "day" = days[,6], "val" = val[,6]))
day7 = data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, "outcome" = outcome, "age" = age, "day" = days[,7], "val" = val[,7]))
```

I am trying to create 7 data frames called `day1` through `day7`. I would also like to pull in information from the corresponding columns in the `days` and `val` data frames. I have written the following for loop but it's not working. Any suggestions?

```
for (i in 1:7) {
  name = paste0("day",i)
  name <- data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, 
                           "outcome" = outcome, 
                           "age" = age, 
                           "day" = days[i], 
                           "val" = val[i]))
}
```

Comment: Consider an `lapply` solution to avoid the bookkeeping of initializing a list and assigning iteratively by index. Also, no need for `cbind` or quoted names: `df_list <- lapply(1:7, function(i) data.frame(ID = data$ID, ..., day = days[,i], val = val[,i]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what you asked for (data frames named dayi from a for loop):

```
day <- list()
for (i in 1:7) {
  day[[i]] <- data.frame(cbind("ID" = data$ID, 
                           "outcome" = outcome, 
                           "age" = age, 
                           "day" = days[i], 
                           "val" = val[i]))
}
```

only difference is that your data frames will be called by day[[i]] instead of dayi. This has the benefit of grouping them all together in one list